# Symfony relationship get by id in Entity without repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have in my Item ORM entity a relationship with Packs.

Now in my code I have a PackId and I have an Item. Now here's what I am trying in my code:

```
$item->getPackById($pack->getId);
```

In my Item Entity I try something like this:

```
public function getPackById(UuidInterface $packId)
{
    return $this->packs[$packId];
}
```

I am not sure If I can do this without a repository or is there a better way?

Comment: So you already have an ORM relationship between `item` and `pack` ? and an item has a `packs` parameter ?

Comment: @DennisdeBest yes correct. I can do `$item->getPacks()` but I want to be afle to get a Pack by Id so just 1

Comment: Adjust your Doctrine mapping to use the [indexBy](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html#mapping-indexed-associations) capability.  After which, return $this->packs[$packId] will work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we try to avoid to much work in an entity but as you are certain that the packs UUID are unique you could try something with an array filter like :

```
    public function getPackById(Uuid $uuid): ?Pack
    {
        $matching =  array_filter((array)$this->packs, fn(Pack $pack) => $pack->getUuid() === $uuid);
        return $matching[0];
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work since `$this->packs` is a collection, the casting to an array doesn't work

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it without a loop since I already now the ID

Comment: not without going through the repository, but as you already have the packs when you call the item this should not add much overhead and prevent you from calling the database a second time

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your comment correctely, the (array) cast doesn't work ? in that case the docrine collection should work with `array_filter($this->packs->toArray(), fn(Pack $pack => ...)` if I recall correctly.